# Access Public Skydrive Content Using Live Connect REST Without Access Token

Tags: rest, onedrive, live-connect-sdk

According to this Microsoft api page
http ://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826522#reading_albums
, I tried to translate this browser access skydrive URL

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=0A263A7CBEAAFB80&sc=photos#cid=0A263A7CBEAAFB80&id=A263A7CBEAAFB80%214521&sc=photos

to

http://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.0A263A7CBEAAFB80.A263A7CBEAAFB80!4521

Since the album is shared to public, I should be allowed to access without access token.

Am I missed something? Or is just using the wrong URL?

I notice I can get public profile by using this
https ://apis.live.net/v5.0/0A263A7CBEAAFB80/

And I have read the REST API

http ://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx
, but I found it is hard to deduce the correct url format

This get all albums 
https ://apis.live.net/v5.0/0A263A7CBEAAFB80/albums

REST URL also fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a guide for this as well, but just noticed that your URL appears to have an additional '/' in it. The one listed on the site is:

https://apis.live.netv5.0/%fileid%

Were you able to get this to work?